# When clicked on any other images apart from first three in the gridview, app abruptly shuts down.

Tags: android, gridview

When I click on any of the first three images in the grid view, I can see that image in the full screen view. But when I click on any of the rest of the images, my app abruptly shuts down. Do you see why? Here is my code:

I am a beginner. I will appreciate any answer and detail explanation.

MainActivity.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.GridView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private GridView gridView;
    private GridViewAdapter gridAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        gridAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(this, R.layout.grid_item_layout, getData());
        gridView.setAdapter(gridAdapter);

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                ImageItem item = (ImageItem) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

                //Create intent
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("title", item.getTitle());
                intent.putExtra("image", item.getImage());

                //Start details activity
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Prepare some dummy data for gridview
     */
    private ArrayList<ImageItem> getData() {
        final ArrayList<ImageItem> imageItems = new ArrayList<>();
        TypedArray imgs = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.image_ids);
        for (int i = 0; i < imgs.length(); i++) {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), imgs.getResourceId(i, -1));
            imageItems.add(new ImageItem(bitmap, "Image#" + i));
        }
        return imageItems;
    }
}
```

DetailsActivity.java

```
public class DetailsActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.details_activity);

        String title = getIntent().getStringExtra("title");
        Bitmap bitmap = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("image");

        TextView titleTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
        titleTextView.setText(title);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
```

GridViewAdapter.java

```
public class GridViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ImageItem> {

    private Context context;
    private int layoutResourceId;
    private ArrayList<ImageItem> data = new ArrayList<ImageItem>();

    public GridViewAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<ImageItem> data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.imageTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.text);
            holder.image = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.image);
            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }


        ImageItem item = data.get(position);
        holder.imageTitle.setText(item.getTitle());
        holder.image.setImageBitmap(item.getImage());
        return row;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView imageTitle;
        ImageView image;
    }
}
```

ImageItem.java

```
public class ImageItem {
    private Bitmap image;
    private String title;

    public ImageItem(Bitmap image, String title) {
        super();
        this.image = image;
        this.title = title;
    }

    public Bitmap getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(Bitmap image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

LogCat

```
02-19 22:32:13.814: I/ActivityManager(661): Killing 2165:com.javatechig.gridviewexample/u0a61 (adj 0): error during init
02-19 22:32:13.861: I/art(2183): Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
02-19 22:32:13.881: I/ActivityManager(661): Start proc com.javatechig.gridviewexample for activity com.javatechig.gridviewexample/.DetailsActivity: pid=2183 uid=10061 gids={50061, 9997} abi=x86
02-19 22:32:13.885: W/ActivityManager(661): Spurious death for ProcessRecord{14ec9f6c 0:com.javatechig.gridviewexample/u0a61}, curProc for 2165: null
02-19 22:32:13.937: E/JavaBinder(661): !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
02-19 22:32:13.937: W/ActivityManager(661): Exception in new application when starting activity com.javatechig.gridviewexample/.DetailsActivity
02-19 22:32:13.937: W/ActivityManager(661): android.os.TransactionTooLargeException
02-19 22:32:13.937: W/ActivityManager(661):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
02-19 22:32:13.937: W/ActivityManager(661):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:496)
02-19 22:32:13.937: W/ActivityManager(661):     at android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy.scheduleLaunchActivity(ApplicationThreadNative.java:793)
02-19 22:32:13.937: W/ActivityManager(661):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.realStartActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1157)
02-19 22:32:13.937: W/ActivityManager(661):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.attachApplicationLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:526)
02-19 22:32:13.937: W/ActivityManager(661):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.attachApplicationLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:6192)
02-19 22:32:13.937: W/ActivityManager(661):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.attachApplication(ActivityManagerService.java:6254)
02-19 22:32:13.937: W/ActivityManager(661):     at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:481)
02-19 22:32:13.937: W/ActivityManager(661):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2407)
02-19 22:32:13.937: W/ActivityManager(661):     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
02-19 22:32:13.937: A/ActivityManager(661): Exception thrown launching activities in ProcessRecord{f202f3b 2183:com.javatechig.gridviewexample/u0a61}
02-19 22:32:13.937: A/ActivityManager(661): android.os.TransactionTooLargeException
02-19 22:32:13.937: A/ActivityManager(661):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
02-19 22:32:13.937: A/ActivityManager(661):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:496)
02-19 22:32:13.937: A/ActivityManager(661):     at android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy.scheduleLaunchActivity(ApplicationThreadNative.java:793)
02-19 22:32:13.937: A/ActivityManager(661):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.realStartActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1157)
02-19 22:32:13.937: A/ActivityManager(661):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.attachApplicationLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:526)
02-19 22:32:13.937: A/ActivityManager(661):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.attachApplicationLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:6192)
02-19 22:32:13.937: A/ActivityManager(661):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.attachApplication(ActivityManagerService.java:6254)
02-19 22:32:13.937: A/ActivityManager(661):     at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:481)
02-19 22:32:13.937: A/ActivityManager(661):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2407)
02-19 22:32:13.937: A/ActivityManager(661):     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
02-19 22:32:13.937: I/ActivityManager(661): Killing 2183:com.javatechig.gridviewexample/u0a61 (adj 0): error during init
02-19 22:32:14.001: W/ActivityManager(661): Force removing ActivityRecord{2922ee79 u0 com.javatechig.gridviewexample/.DetailsActivity t91}: app died, no saved state
02-19 22:32:14.024: W/ActivityManager(661): Spurious death for ProcessRecord{f202f3b 0:com.javatechig.gridviewexample/u0a61}, curProc for 2183: null
02-19 22:32:14.105: W/EGL_emulation(1016): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-19 22:32:14.105: W/OpenGLRenderer(1016): Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xe29a1260, error=EGL_SUCCESS
02-19 22:32:14.152: W/InputMethodManagerService(661): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 2130 uid 10061
02-19 22:36:33.443: I/UsageStatsService(661): User[0] Flushing usage stats to disk
02-19 22:46:35.208: I/ProcessStatsService(661): Prepared write state in 0ms
02-19 22:46:35.208: I/ProcessStatsService(661): Prepared write state in 0ms
02-19 22:46:54.854: I/ActivityManager(661): Killing 1044:com.android.printspooler/u0a50 (adj 13): empty for 1813s
02-19 22:46:54.882: I/ActivityManager(661): Killing 1587:com.android.calendar/u0a21 (adj 13): empty for 1813s
02-19 22:46:54.915: I/ActivityManager(661): Killing 1640:com.android.email/u0a31 (adj 13): empty for 1813s
02-19 22:46:54.946: I/ActivityManager(661): Killing 1669:com.android.exchange/u0a32 (adj 13): empty for 1813s
02-19 22:46:54.975: I/ActivityManager(661): Killing 1506:com.android.mms/u0a8 (adj 13): empty for 1813s
02-19 22:46:55.093: D/CountryDetector(661): No listener is left
02-19 22:46:55.103: I/ActivityManager(661): Killing 1241:android.process.media/u0a5 (adj 15): empty for 1813s
02-19 22:46:55.159: W/art(661): Long monitor contention event with owner method=void com.android.server.am.BroadcastQueue.processNextBroadcast(boolean) from BroadcastQueue.java:542 waiters=1 for 244ms
02-19 22:46:55.159: W/libprocessgroup(661): failed to open /acct/uid_10021/pid_1587/cgroup.procs: No such file or directory
02-19 22:46:55.159: W/art(661): Long monitor contention event with owner method=void com.android.server.am.BroadcastQueue.processNextBroadcast(boolean) from BroadcastQueue.java:542 waiters=2 for 217ms
02-19 22:46:55.159: W/libprocessgroup(661): failed to open /acct/uid_10031/pid_1640/cgroup.procs: No such file or directory
02-19 22:46:55.161: W/art(661): Long monitor contention event with owner method=void com.android.server.am.BroadcastQueue.processNextBroadcast(boolean) from BroadcastQueue.java:542 waiters=3 for 183ms
02-19 22:46:55.161: W/libprocessgroup(661): failed to open /acct/uid_10032/pid_1669/cgroup.procs: No such file or directory
02-19 22:46:55.162: W/libprocessgroup(661): failed to open /acct/uid_10008/pid_1506/cgroup.procs: No such file or directory
02-19 22:46:55.163: W/libprocessgroup(661): failed to open /acct/uid_10005/pid_1241/cgroup.procs: No such file or directory
02-19 22:46:55.164: W/libprocessgroup(661): failed to open /acct/uid_10050/pid_1044/cgroup.procs: No such file or directory
02-19 22:47:34.854: I/ActivityManager(661): Killing 1403:com.android.providers.calendar/u0a1 (adj 15): empty for 1819s
02-19 22:47:34.909: W/libprocessgroup(661): failed to open /acct/uid_10001/pid_1403/cgroup.procs: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a `android.os.TransactionTooLargeException` and from the name it is because you are passing big objects like Bitmaps on the intent. You should only pass a reference to it, like the URL or the drawable id from the resources like in your case.

More Details on when you get the [TransactionTooLargeException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/TransactionTooLargeException.html)

> During a remote procedure call, the arguments and the return value of
>   the call are transferred as Parcel objects stored in the Binder
>   transaction buffer. If the arguments or the return value are too large
>   to fit in the transaction buffer, then the call will fail and
>   TransactionTooLargeException will be thrown.
>
> The Binder transaction buffer has a limited fixed size, currently **1Mb**,
>   which is shared by all transactions in progress for the process.
>   Consequently this exception can be thrown when there are many
>   transactions in progress even when most of the individual transactions
>   are of moderate size.

Comment: Hey Ahmed, thank you for your answer. I am just a beginner. For last two days, I searched all over,  but could not find / understand how I would pass drawable id from the resources. Would you be able to help? I would really appreciate as much code as possible. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are facing this exception because other images except the first 3 images are too large to pass with intent.

You can just pass the image uri or image id of clicked item with the intent then and use that on DetailsActivity.